# What is a Mattering Word™?

Tags: word-property

Here are some examples of words I call Mattering Words™, and those that I do not call Mattering Words™. The Mattering Words™ I give are not the only examples of Mattering Words™; there are many more.

| Mattering Words™ | Not Mattering Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| WARM | COOL |
| IMITATION | COPY |
| LATITUDE | LONGITUDE |
| WIPES | TOWELS |
| OMIT | KEEP |
| TOWS | DRAGS |
| LIGHT | DARK |
| HEARS | SEES |
| EIGHT | SEVEN |

CSV version for hardcore analysis:

```
Mattering Words™,Not Mattering Words™
WARM,COOL
IMITATION,COPY
LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
WIPES,TOWELS
OMIT,KEEP
TOWS,DRAGS
LIGHT,DARK
HEARS,SEES
EIGHT,SEVEN
```

All this being said, it's now up to you to figure it out. **What is a Mattering Word™?**

HINT:

> Don't overthink it.

Comment: sees may be an issue, too because rot13(hfrrf) is a word according to webster, but I edited my answer to account for that :)

Comment: @SteveV: rot13(hfrrf) was quite difficult to see, and I missed it. Your original was the intended answer, but I'll have to acknowledge that your finding of a loophole to combat it goes beyond the prompt.

Comment: Hooray, one for the Scrabble players! (the technical term is hook)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a mattering word is

> one which becomes another word when a single letter (a consonant) is added to the front (mattering is one... smattering)

As follows:

> cold --> scold
>  warm --> swarm
>  imitation --> limitation
>  latitude --> platitude
>  wipes --> swipes
>  omits --> vomits
>  tows  --> stows
>  light --> flight
>  hears --> shears
>  eight --> weight

Comment: "Heat" would be in the wrong section in this case, no?

Comment: @jafe yes.  burst my bubble!

Comment: @jafe: Mistake on my part! I was quite dumb. (heat --> cheat)